# group by alias in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle10g

[image: example]

I need get all state (1,2,3,4) with out duplicates.

```
1 xxx
2 yyy
3 zzz
4 jjj
```

My first and only idea was get all state and group them:

```
select state1 as state,desc1 as desc from table where id=X
Union
select state2 as state,desc2 as desc from table where id=X
```

This get in the example 6 rows. So, to discard the duplicate I try to use a alias:

```
select state,desc from 
(
select state1 as state,desc1 as desc from table where id=X
    Union
    select state2 as state,desc2 as desc from table where id=X
)
group by state;
```

But I got the error is not a GROUP BY expression.

I saw similar questions but I can't resolve the problem.

Comment: What are the data types of the columns - can you add the DDL and insert statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UNION should remove any duplicates. If it doesn't then you should check the data -- maybe you have extra spaces in the text columns.

Try something like this.

```
select state1 as state,TRIM(desc1) as desc from table where id=X
Union
select state2 as state,TRIM(desc2) as desc from table where id=X
```

Comment: this worked correctly, thanks you very much for al you advice..regard

Answer (score 5):

All the select-list items have to either be in the group by, or be aggregates. You could include both `state, desc` in the group-by clause, but it would be neater to use `distinct` instead; however, `union` (without `all`) suppresses duplicates anyway, so neither is needed here.

As Bluefeet mentioned elsewhere, `desc` is a keyword and has a meaning in order-by clauses, so it is not a good name for a column or alias.

This gets four rows, not six:

```
select state1 as state_x, desc1 as desc_x from t42 where id = 'X'
union
select state2 as state_x, desc2 as desc_x from t42 where id = 'X';

| STATE_X | DESC_X |
|---------|--------|
|       1 |    xxx |
|       2 |    yyy |
|       3 |    zzz |
|       4 |    jjj |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5b900/2). It isn't clear why you think you're getting six rows, or what you are really doing differently.

Comment: thanks very much, this help me to tried the advice of dimm, of the next answer. The trim in the select fields, got the correct result, with out alias.

Answer (score 2):

Your first query doesn't work probably because *desc1* and *desc2* columns have different types e.g. *char(10)* and *char(20)*. Here is an [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c77c3/1/0) from SQL Fiddle that shows this effect. If you change *char(20)* to *char(10)* in the left pane the query will work.

Comment: I might suggest escaping the `desc`, I'm pretty sure that is a reserved word.

Comment: Your example uses MySQL and not Oracle. The results are different (see my first example).

Comment: I removed my second example because it doesn't work in Oracle.